# Удалить все записи, дата которых прошла

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица, в INT значении хранится UNIX дата (кол-во секунд).
Как составить SQL-запрос, чтобы записи, где текущий UNIX >= UNIX дата в таблице удалялись?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подойдет?

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE time_column<UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```